# Get location from response header

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get the `Location` value from a `POST` request using python's requests module. However, when I look at the response's headers, I don't see any such key. Performing the same request using Google Chrome does show the key.

This is where I am trying to download data from: https://data.police.uk/data
. Launch this in Google Chrome and open the Developer Tools. When you select a date range, select some force and click `Generate File`, you can see a `POST` request being made with a `Location` key in the Response header.

```
import requests
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin

BASE = 'https://data.police.uk'
FORM_PATH = 'data'

form_url = urljoin(BASE, FORM_PATH)

# Get data download URL
client = requests.session()
try:
    client.get(form_url)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print (e)
    sys.exit()

csrftoken = client.cookies.values()

l = [('forces', 'cleveland')]
t = ('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken[0])

d_from = ('date_from', '2014-05')
d_to = ('date_to', '2016-05')
l.extend((t, d_from, d_to))

r = client.post(form_url, headers=dict(Referer=form_url), data=l)
```

Querying the response headers gives me:

```
In [4]: r.headers
Out[4]: {'Content-Length': '4332', 'Content-Language': 'en-gb', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Set-Cookie': 'csrftoken=aGQ7kO4tQ2cPD0Fp2svxxYBRe4rAk0kw; expires=Thu, 03-Aug-2017 22:11:44 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/', 'Vary': 'Cookie, Accept-Language', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Thu, 04 Aug 2016 22:11:44 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
```

Question: How do I get the `Location` key from the response header?

**EDIT**

Answer: Had to specify `l.append(['include_crime', 'on'])`. Works after this.

Comment: Did you check the body of the response? It usually contains the requested data.

Comment: @trans1st0r : how would I get the response header from body of the requested data?

Comment: Try some of the commands from here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: I know where to look up the docs; my comment was more about the concept of getting response header from requested data doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I mean that when you request data over http, you get a response which contains a header section and body section. The info you need is more likely to be in the body which seems to be `r.content`. Have you tried outputting r.content?

Comment: 1. In the browser, it is listed under headers.
2. Here's the content: http://pastebin.com/raw/6PP4HHip

Answer (score -1):

## EDIT2

You need to pass the `include_crime = on` statement as well, since you are not selecting any dataset. On the webpage if you don't select any checkbox, you will get the same page and you will not get any location header. That is why your r.content has "Please select at least one dataset".

Comment: No, the CSRF validation for you `... CSRF verification failed. Request aborted...` With proper CSRF token, I don't see any problem with robots.txt

Comment: it didnt work, i gave a proper token dude, have appended my program as an edit

Comment: Can you please post your r.content

Comment: You need to pass the include_crime = on statement as well, since you are not selecting any dataset. On the webpage if you don't select any checkbox, you will get the same page and you will not get any location header. That is why your r.content has  "Please select at least one dataset", you can do a Ctrl-F to search for it. That is why I modified the code to include that parameter and the r.content is what I get after posting all parameters correctly to the form.

Comment: It works after I specify `l.append(['include_crime', 'on'])`. I am not sure why yours is failing still.